# AWS Lambda function requests work from local but not in cloud

Tags: lambda, serverless

I have an AWS Lambda function that I am deploying with the serverless framework.

```
module.exports.testFunction = async event => {
  const names = [
    'cazum8videos',
    'tensterakdary',
    'annitheduck',
    'freshlobsterccg',
    'lory',
    'brksedu',
    'thedarkness',
    'mentschannel',
    'sambzockt',
  ]

  const test = await Promise.all(
    names.map(async (name, idx) => {
      await throttle().then(async () => {
        const url = `https://twitchtracker.com/api/channels/summary/${name}`
        try {
          const r = await axios.get(url)
          console.log(r.data)
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e)
        }
      })
    })
  )
  return 'test done'
}
```

(throttle is a function that will delay each request so that I won't run into too many requests)

This function calls an api `Twitchtracker` to get some Twitch data for particular accounts, and it works just fine when I invoke this function locally via `sls invoke local --function testFunction`.

The problem is, that for some reason it does not work in AWS and for every call I'm receiving a `503` code. Can someone hint me with a reason on why this does not work in the cloud but on my local, and what I could do about this?

Comment: Because you configured the lambda in a VPC subnet with internet access!?

Comment: @luk2302 other requests coming from that Lambda calling Google services works just fine.